# My own cryptographic algorithm

Tags: cryptography

I am wondering if it is possible for someone to break your key and algorithm if you made them by yourself and no one knows neither the key or the algorithm.
What do you think?

Comment: Effective cryptographic algorithms are created by professionals with a deep understanding of cryptography and cryptanalysis.   If you aren't one then your scheme will be broken.

Comment: Google "Schneier's Law" and "Kerckhoffs's principle"

Comment: We don't know your application, but you could use a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) if you want theoretically unbreakable.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have to ask the question, then you are not a cryptography expert.  If you are not an expert, then your encryption will be breakable by an expert.

One Sunday, the Ruritanian Secret Service detect a coded radio message from Freedonia to the Freedonian embassy in Ruritania.  On the Monday, the Freedonian ambassador delivers a diplomatic note to the Ruritanian Foreign Minister, complaining about Ruritanian Yak herders grazing their animals on the wrong side of the border.  The encoded message and the diplomatic note are the same length.

The Ruritanian Secret Service now have a copy of the intercepted cyphertext, and the matching plaintext, as delivered to the Foreign Minister.  This situation is so common that it has a name: "Known Plaintext Attack".  If the key can be recovered, then any other messages using that key can be decrypted, even when the plaintext is not already known.  Can your cipher resist a known plaintext attack?  Do you know how to design a cipher that can resist such an attack?

@CodesInChaos' advice is good.

Answer (score 0):

Oh sure it's possible. It has happened many times in history. The only algorithm that is not breakable in this (and any other) way is properly used [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

In any other case it's usually a matter of intercepting sufficient amount of messages encrypted with the same key. Then you can reason about the algorithm. If you happen to find pair of plaintext + cyphertext of the same message then the analysis is even simpler.

Imagine you have encryption algorithm called **multiplication** and decryption algorithm called **division**. Symmetric key is **4**.

Scenario: Alice wants to send "12" to Bob.

1. Alice takes "12" and encrypts it using the key -> 12 * 4 = 48.
2. Alice sends "48" to Bob.
3. Bob gets "48" and decrypts it using the same key -> 48 / 4 = 12.
4. Bobs reads message "12".

Now wonder how many pairs of plain/cyphertext you'd need to figure out what's the algorithm or even how many encrypted messages given you'd have known how to recognize that something has been decrypted properly (i.e. after decryption forms a dictionary word etc.). Not so hard, isn't it?

Of course this example is trivial and complex algorithms require more advanced analysis but usually using the same key for encrypting different data is enough to figure out what's going on if you have enough data available.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they could break it even if they didn't know the key or the algorithm.  Odds are though, they won't.

It's kinda going overboard to write your own cryptographic algorithm purely for this purpose.  It doesn't actually make you that much more secure. My advice: focus on keeping your key secret, not on keeping the algorithm secret.